# multido: vertical vector

Tags: pstricks, axis, number, multido

From the first page of [multido documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/multido/multido-doc.pdf) we can see a horizontal vector with a  fixed-point addition system. Can I create the same vector, but vertically?
Alternatively, are there better ways to add points to an axis in an orderly fashion, without having to use the axis environment?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Ti*k*Z does not have an `axis` environment, `pgfplots` has. There are tons of different ways of creating axes, and several proposals exist in answers on this site. What precisely do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you really want a vector, or just a vertical graduated axis?

Comment: Just a vertical graduated axis

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use explicitly `multido`– just have to use the `\psaxis` command, with the relevant parameters:

```
        \documentclass[11pt]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}

        \usepackage{pst-plot, auto-pst-pdf}

        \begin{document}

        \fbox{\begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(0.5,6)
        \psset{unit = 3cm}%
        \psaxes[arrows=->, xAxis=false, Dy=0.25, dy=0.25, labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](0,0)(0,0)(0,2)[,0][$y$, -135]
        \end{pspicture*}}

        \end{document}
```

In this code `Dy=` specifies the label increment, and `dy=` the spacing between consecutive labels on the $y$-axis.
[image]